# What is this thing on top of my GPU? (Looks like paper)

Tags: gpu

Today I disassembled my laptop for the first time, to clean it from dusts and replace its thermal paste.

But when I remove the cooling system, I saw something different in my GPU, it looks like paper, I don't know what it is and if it is necessary.

Do you know what is this and what is it for?

[image: papery thing]

If you know what it is, can you tell me its name or where can I buy it?

Comment: Never seen one before, but best guess it just keeps excess thermal paste from contacting motherboard components, as some pastes conduct electricity. If it is in good shape leave it there.